# check wcf client connection

Tags: wcf, duplex

I am creating a client service application using WCF duplex callback. The service sends messages to all connected clients. I am storing all connected clients in the dictionary. Before sending message to the client I want to check if any client has shutdown abnormally (network disconnection, power off).

@marc_s: I created a CheckCallbackChannels method which will check for Communication State of a connected clients in the dictionary.

```
Sub CheckCallbackChannel()
    For Each objClient As KeyValuePair(Of Guid, IClientCallBack) In MainService.objClients
        Dim objClientCallBack As IClientCallBack = MainService.objClients.Item(objClient.Key)
        Dim callbackChannel As ICommunicationObject = TryCast(mobjClientCallBack,ICommunicationObject)
        'Dim state As CommunicationState = callbackChannel.State
        If callbackChannel.State = CommunicationState.Opened OrElse callbackChannel.State = CommunicationState.Faulted Then
            MainService.objClients.Remove(objClient.Key)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

but here i get the state as connected for faulty clients also.

Comment: @marc_s:I created a CheckCallbackChannels method which will check for all Communication State  state of a connected clients in the dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could include a `Ping()` method on each service contract, and call that before your actual call.

But what does that really tell you??

First of all, even the call to `.Ping()` could result in an exception (since the service is gone, overloaded, whatever).

And if it succeeds - it gives you absolutely **no guarantee** that your next call to that same service, a microsecond later, has any chance of succeeding....

Basically, I find this approach wasteful - you need to write a lot of code, and in the end, it really doesn't give you any meaningful information.

What you need to do is: be prepared on **every** service call that it can fail - for whatever reason. Don't waste your time and processing cycles pinging around all over your system - it doesn't give you any meaningful info anyway.

Just make your service calls, be prepared to handle failures (and possibly recycle your WCF proxies) - and that's all you can really do.